# Creating executables from jar

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar

I have created jar file in java.  It uses some library files.  so, the final structure I have is,

- example.jar
- lib

  - library files

How to convert them into a single file, like an exe for windows?  It should run in linux also, like (.sh files - NetBeans installer).

Comment: I doubt you can write an executable that runs under Linux and Windows. Why not creating a jar file containing your codes and the libraries?

Comment: *"No negative votes for this please."*  Do some research in future, please.  1) Many of the 'Java to EXE' questions mention [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) as a better alternative for any app. with a GUI.  Did you read any of those, does the app. have a GUI? Do you have reasons for not wanting to use the Oracle technology that makes this possible for Windows, *nix & OS X? 2) You don't avoid down-votes by politely requesting none, instead you avoid them by asking a good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Netbeans check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/single-jar-141905.html) for join all jars in one, now when you have 1 jar you can create the exe with [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Just make a JAR packed with all the library dependencies.

1. If Maven is your build tool, check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven). There are similar solutions for other tools (Gradle etc).
2. Some IDEs are also capable of this, for instance [Netbeans](http://www.lampos.net/netbeans) and [IntelliJ IDEA](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/) are.

Of course be sure, that the libraries you want to pack have a license that permits this.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is possible it is against Java nature.

Java was designed as a portable language (write once, run anywhere); your .jar file contains Java bytecode, which is to be interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine at runtime; you can copy it to any architecture and it will run there.

An .exe file actually contains machine code specific language which is to be directly ran by the processors; this will not work on another architecture.

However there are different tools for your need like [JarToExe](http://www.brothersoft.com/jartoexe-75019.html) or [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: The architecture isn't really the issue here, virtually any processor used for Desktop/Laptop PC's will understand x86 machine code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

- Compile to a native application with something like gcj. This isn't an option in many cases though (you'll see why if you look into it)
- Have a modified `java` executable that runs your jar
- Have an executable that runs your jar with java

If you can reasonably assume your clients have java installed, it should be fine to just deploy an executable jar though - on most Desktop OS'es the java distribution is set up to run executable jars in the expected fashion (i.e. by double clicking in Windows), and on those where it's not - well, people will likely know what java is and how to run jars.